# How to change modifier after applying? And is it right to apply modifier before UV mapping?

Tags: uv, modifiers

Sorry for my simple question first. I'm new to blender.  Now I encountered the problem that I want to delete the modifier after applying. I wonder if there are ways that can delete the modifier. Or after apply, the modifier can't change?

And I've learned that I should apply the modifier before UV mapping.  Is it right to apply modifier before UV mapping? If not, what is the necessary or best time to apply modifier?

Comment: If you apply the modifier it will be deleted in the Modifiers menu, but sometimes you should better keep it, for example it's better to keep a Subsurf modifier as it will save memory. I guess it's necessary to apply it if you want to export to other softwares. Some other modifiers like Mirror need to be applied when for example you have to rig your object with an armature. About UV mapping: you don't need to apply a Subsurf but you'd better apply a Mirror modifier.

Comment: plus keep in mind that if you apply a Subsurf, not only it will weight much heavier,  but it will be much harder to rework the topology if necessary, so if you do it for some reason, keep the original version with Subsurf not applied